# RegEx solution for 1.23+1.23+1

Tags: regex

I searched a lot but can not find this regular expression. My problem is that I made a calculator but can not validate my display entirely. My case is with the dot 
I need my regular expression to be: digit dot digit operator digit dot ( `1.23+1.23+1.`). The dot must be placed only once not like (`1..23+ 1.1.1`). I have found similar regular expression but it didn't cover the case (`1.23 +1.`) 
Here is my regEx -> `/[0-9-+/*]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/g`

Comment: will it do : /[0-9-+*]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/g

Comment: Can you clarify which language this regular expression is being used with?

Comment: I guess JavaScript judging by provided regex.

Comment: Yea sorry yes JavaScript -4 comments on this for my first post....Sorry to upset you guys

Answer (score 0):

Check this out([demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO6dR7/1)):

```
/^(([-+*\/ ]+)?(\b(\d+\.\d+)\b|\d))+$/
```

but it will work only if there is one equation per string - it matches at beginning (`^`) and ant the end (`$`) of a string. However you can also use it with `/m` or/and `/g` modifiers.

**EDIT**

If it is only about '–' character it is enough to add it to character class:

```
/^(([-–+*\/ ]+)?(\b(\d+\.\d+)\b|\d))+$/
```

Comment: Thanks this is very good. I need the expression to cover one more thing, last symbol can be operator too (1.23 + 2.33+)

Comment: @KonstantinPopov do you mean you want to cover a paretheses also? or just the last + or - ?

Comment: No no parentheses only operators + - * / :) . My idea is to have calculator screen where i can type valid equations and i need regex to validate every type on display. Calculator have only primary function like + - * /

Comment: @KonstantinPopov I updated my answer, is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Could use this

`^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[+-](?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*$`

Expanded:

```
 ^                             # BOS
 [+-]?                         # Optional Plus or minus
 (?:                           # Decimal term
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 (?:                           # Optionally, many more terms
      [+-]                          # Required Plus or minus
      (?:                           # Decimal term
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
 )*
 $                             # EOS
```